# GStreamer: Using type find

Tags: ffmpeg, gstreamer, mpeg

I've got a filesrc connected to a typefind element. On the "have-type" signal I print out the capibilities. What can I do with this information? I.e:

```
"Media type video/mpeg, systemstream=(boolean)false, mpegversion=(int)4, parsed=(boolean)false found, probability 79%"
```

Can I search for compatible elements or do I have to process this manually? How do I decide what the next element in the pipeline should be?

Also, please do not suggest using playbin2 - it is not suitable for my application.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This tells you at least whats in your file. Now you might want to connect a demux (according to typefinds info) and use the demultiplexers "pad-added" signal to process the media streams inside. (until it says "no-more-pads")

http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/manual/html/section-dynamic.html

Comment: Can typefind information be used as a "GstPluginFeature" (mentioned in the link) - I think this what I might be looking for...

Answer (score 1):

```
uridecode2 ,playbin2 ,decodebin2
```

this all are auto-pluggers means you just need to give some input file name they will automatically create pipeline for that.

1st they take filesrc element and open that file and depending upon some header info they set caps of filesrc.

so now depending upon the caps of filesrc's src pad next demuxer is going to find from registery and it linked ...and so on

and i think you are going to some kind of this things in your application so i suggest you to one look in this autoplugger's source code..

start with playbin2 code..

Comment: Thanks again Mr.32, +1 for usefulness. Not quite sure if I can accept this as an answer yet though. I'll have a look at the source and see what I come up with. Regards.

Comment: another good option is prepare pipeline with such autopluggers and enable --gst-debug=5 and dump all logs in file and study them..it will also help you to understand this